# UI para design de relatórios para PHP

Tags: php, mysql, relatório

Eu já utilizei muito o Crystal Reports para criar visualmente meus relatórios baseado em consultas no banco de dados. Era muito fácil agrupar informações repetidas na consulta.

Tenho procurado softwares ou bibliotecas PHP para fazer a mesma coisa em ambiente web, ou seja, relatórios em páginas PHP buscando de uma base MySQL. Não encontrei nada que consiga atender de forma tão eficiente. Preciso ficar fazendo manualmente cada relatório e trabalhar os loops, ifs, totais etc.

Existe algum software onde eu modele visualmente meu relatório, com seus agrupamentos etc, então gere um código HTML+PHP para relatórios dinâmicos?

Comment: De vez em quando tem algo http://alternativeto.net/software/crystal-reports/?platform=online

Comment: @brasofilo, infelizmente nenhuma das aplicações semelhantes é possível. Porém vi que o Crystal Reports tem uma versão web, vou pesquisar, mas de qualquer forma é uma aplicação muito cara. Valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa interessante é o [iReport](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) que é uma ferramenta desenvolvida pela mesma empresa do [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) (muito usado em Java). Há pelo menos duas maneiras possíveis de usar os relatórios gerados no ambiente visual do iReport pelo php, mantendo um servidor Java onde o php se conecta no Java por meio do [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) ou usando a Classe [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML) (em php puro). Dessa forma você usa uma ferramenta específica para desenvolver relatório (esqueci de mencionar que é gratuita), ela gera um arquivo jrxml (um xml) que é o arquivo de relatório. Depois é só usar o PHPJasperXML para interpretar ou usar o JasperReport via PHP/Java Bridge. No youtube tem vários vídeos ensinado usar, vou deixar um link para um [vídeo ensinando a fazer um relatório básico, caso queria verificar um pouco mais sobre o iReport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDqxBYoU3dM). Espero que tenha serviço para esclarecer sua dúvida. O tutorial completo de como usar eu vou ficar devendo.

Comment: Obrigado Sileno. É um volta que talvez terei que dar. Acredito que ainda assim é mais fácil do que ficar criando HTML e Loops/cálculos na mão em PHP.