# Gerador de relatórios para PHP

Tags: php, ireport, jasper-reports

Pessoal alguém pode me indicar uma ferramenta `Gerador de relatório` que possibilite integração com o `PHP`, neste link: [UI para design de relatórios para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31279/ui-para-design-de-relat%C3%B3rios-para-php), há informações sobre o **iReport**, pois eu já até andei usando  ele, que por sinal é uma ótima ferramenta, porém a sua biblioteca no **PHP** a **PHPJasperXML** parece que foi descontinuada (segundo informações que encontrei na web), com isso há recursos do `iReport` que a biblioteca não suporta. Há alguma alternativa ao **iReport** ?

Comment: realmente o iReport é uma ótima escolha como gerador de relatórios, porém sua integração com o PHP não estar muito legal mesmo, também estou tendo alguns problemas semelhantes ...

Comment: Cara, to usando a versão 5.6 do JasperDesigner, tem algumas coisas que nao funciona, mais ta sendo bem

Comment: Olá, sei exatamente o que você precisa é da biblioteca [phpjasper](https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper), realmente é muito boa. segue o link: https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper

Comment: Encontrei um repositório no github "Quilhasoft/jasperPHP" com uma biblioteca PURO PHP que gera PDF a partir do arquivo JRXML, tem sido muito útil para min,
https://github.com/QuilhaSoft/JasperPHP