# Ireport e php 7.0

Tags: netbeans, ireport

Boa tarde pessoal!
Uso o Ireport para gerar relatórios,no php 5.6 ele funciona de boa, e muito bem por sinal, mas no php 7.x.x ele apresenta o seguinte erro ao tentar gerar um relatório:

> ErrorException in PHPJasperXML.inc.php line 4:
>
> Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in
>   a future version of PHP; PHPJasperXML has a deprecated constructor

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como resolver?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O iReport como gerador de relatório atualmente exibe esta mensagem informando que tal recurso é considerado obsoleto. Até mesmo para versão PHP5 que ele roda, vem dando alguns bugs. Há algo sobre este problema aqui: [Gerador de relatórios para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127523/gerador-de-relat%C3%B3rios-para-php)

Você pode tentar outro gerador, veja: https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper

Comment: Obrigado Fabiano